# TYPO3 split different wrap for first line using optionSplit

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I am getting the text from the abstract field and splitting it by new line.
What I want is to wrap the first line in an H5 tag and all lines after in P tags.

This is what I have tried:

```
tt_content.menu.20.102 = HMENU
tt_content.menu.20.102 {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    NO = 1
    NO {
      doNotLinkIt = 1
      stdWrap.cObject = COA
      stdWrap.cObject {

        50 = TEXT
        50.stdWrap {
          field = abstract
          split {
            token.char = 10
            cObjNum = 1 || 2
            1.current = 1
            1.wrap = <h5>|</h5>
            2.current = 1
            2.wrap = <p>|</p>
          }
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it wraps all the lines in H5... How do I make this work?

Comment: your code works fine for me; I am using TYPO3 9.5.4 - will try with 7.6.x ASAP

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi In case it makes a difference I have added some of the surrounding menu typoscript for context...

Comment: I don't understand why it happens, but it seems that the split is done on the whole group of all the abstract fields. I explain: if you have two pages in your menu ONE that has abstract=aa;bb (I use ; as split token) and TWO that has abstract=cc;dd , then the result is that aa,bb are wrapped with <h5> while cc,dd are wrapped with <p>

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi You're right. I didn't notice that because I tested with only 1 page. Do you have any suggestions? or perhaps an alternative way to do the same thing?

Comment: I don't know if it is the same issue; I could suggest you to join Slack where you could find some help on the typo3-cms channel (link: https://my.typo3.org/index.php?id=35)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi If you see comment #3 https://forge.typo3.org/issues/59533#note-3 He mentions Split in menus, so I am thinking it's the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found a bug report that mentions this issue here: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/59533

It seems the best workaround that I can see is to instead use `listNum`
This has the obvious drawback of only working with a limited number of paragraphs but at least it sort of works.

```
10 = TEXT
10.field = abstract
10.wrap = <h5>|</h5>
10.listNum = 0
10.listNum.splitChar = 10

20 < .10
20.wrap = <p>|</p>
20.listNum = 1

30 < .20
30.listNum = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a combination of both, the original code and the listNum workaround should do the job. Still have to find a way to get the rest of the first "split" into the second one. So consider this answer to be WIP please. We are still discussing it on our Coders.Care Twitch channel in the TYPO3 service station.

```
10 = TEXT
10.field = abstract
10.wrap = <h5>|</h5>
10.listNum = 0
10.listNum.splitChar = 10

20 < .10
20.listNum = 1
20.split {
    token.char = 10
    cObjNum = 1
    1.current = 1
    1.wrap = <p>|</p>
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use replace to turn the first new line character to a special character, then use listNum on that special? (Also +1 goggles are cool)